# If the group is infinite , what inference should I make about the number of nonidentity elements that satisfy the equation $x^5=e$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, infinite-groups

In a finite group, show that the number of nonidentity elements
that satisfy the equation $x^5=e$ is a multiple of 4. If the stipulation
that the group be finite is omitted, what can you say about the
number of nonidentity elements that satisfy the equation $x^5=e$?

I have done the first part, but I don't know what inference should I make when G is infinite?

Comment: Probably the expected answer is just, "either infinitely many or a finite multiple of $4$". (You can make groups of any cardinality where every nonidentity element has order $5$).

Comment: do you have any particular example in your mind of such kind, though I can "feel" there is one but not able to find any concrete examples.(for infinite cases)

Comment: The direct sum of sufficiently many copies of $C_5$ will do. That is, let $A$ be a set of your desired cardinality, and consider the group of all maps $f:A\to\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ which map cofinitely many elements of $A$ to $0$, with the group operation being pointwise addition modulo $5$.